# Как с помощью регулярных выражение убрать фрагмент кода?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, pcre

**Фрагмент кода:**

```
...
<div>
    <div class="product-title">
        <a href="#">Title<span class="last-word">4.0</span></a>        
    </div>
</div>
...
```

**Нужно убрать:**

```
<div class="product-title">
       <a href="#">Title<span class="last-word">4.0</span></a>        
</div>
```

**Моя проба:**

```
 #<div class="product-title">\s*.+\s*<\/div>#ui
```

P.S. Моя проба рабочая, но я видел более универсальное решение, так как внутри могут быть и другие теги (кроме `<div>`)

Comment: Какой язык программирования используется?

Comment: @XelaNimed, php

Comment: А по какой причине нельзя использовать [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)?

Comment: @XelaNimed, мне казалось, что регулярным выражением будет немного быстрее с точки производительности и реализации. К тому же, есть вероятсность не валидности документа ( с ошибками, типа не закрытый тег и т.п)

Comment: На мой взгляд это зависит от размера документа, поставленной задачи и т.д.. Регулярным выражением может быть и быстрее и медленней, в зависимости от его сложности, помимо этого, при изменении структуры HTML может быть проблематично сопровождение монструозной регулярки. В любом случае решать Вам.

Comment: @XelaNimed, а что насчет не валидного кода? Кода с ошибками,  разве  DOMDocument сможет адекватно работать?

Comment: Ты вопросик пропустил в регулярке.

Comment: @Qwertiy, где именно? Для меня символ знака "?" только как 1 или 0

Comment: @Node_pro, после плюса - переключение в нежадный режим.

Comment: @Node_pro, и последний плюс явно лишний.

Comment: @Qwertiy, `#<div class="product-title">\s*.+?\s*<\/div>#ui`?

Comment: @Node_pro, ага.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а как поступить, если у меня каждый тег начинался с новой строки? Мой вариант не думаю, что можно назвать универсальным

Comment: @Node_pro, это только ты сам ответить можешь. Или используй парсер как написали.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант, который вырезает элемент любого типа(тег должен быть сбалансированым), у которого определен класс `product-title` (классов у элемента может быть несколько) вместе со всеми дочерними элементами(если есть) любой вложенности. Теги дочерних элементов могут быть несбалансированными(например: `<input ... />`) или отсутствовать вовсе. Шаблон не чувствителен к форматированию текста.

Для извлечения тегов элементов, в шаблоне используются: [backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html); модификатор `s` - метасимвол `.` включает также и перевод строк.

```
<?php
$input = <<< EOT
<div>
    <div class="product-title">
        <a href="#">Title<span class="last-word">4.0</span></a>        
    </div>
</div>
EOT;

$output = preg_replace(
    "#<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*?\bclass=\".*?\bproduct-title\b.*?\">[^<]*?(?:<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*?>.*?(?:</\\2>)?)?[^<]*?</\\1>#sui",
    "",
    $input
);

echo $output;
```

[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/5jFqkl/2) с более сложной иерархией дочерних элементов у вырезаемого элемента